# Email body sent in HTML

Tags: python, django

I am sending email from tinymce to all subscribed users using this view:

```
def send_newsletter(request):
    form = NewsLetterEmailForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        newsltr = NewsLetterEmail.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        print(newsltr.status)

        if newsltr.status == 'Published':
            subject = newsltr.subject
            body = mark_safe(newsltr.body)
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER

            for newsletter_obj in NewsLetter.objects.all():
                send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email,
                          message=body, recipient_list=[newsletter_obj.email])

    return render(request, 'newsletter/send-email.html', {'form': form})
```

but content of email is sent in html:

```
<p><span style="font-family: 'arial black', sans-serif; font-size: 18pt;"><strong>Completely optimize efficient internal</strong></span></p>
<p>or "organic" sources with fully tested schemas. Enthusiastically aggregate mission-critical infrastructures via top-line content. Objectively matrix cutting-edge bandwidth before viral action items. Objectively matrix viral users after sticky processes. Dramatically harness adaptive meta-services rather than scalable e-commerce.</p>
```

I used `mark_safe()` method hoping it will work, but it didn't. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out how to do it using `EmailMultiAlternative()`, replacing this part of the code solves the problem.

```
    if newsltr.status == 'Published':
        subject = newsltr.subject
        body = newsltr.body
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER

        for newsletter_obj in NewsLetter.objects.all():
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                subject, body, from_email, [newsletter_obj.email])
            msg.attach_alternative(body, "text/html")
            msg.send()
```

Comment: You shouldn't send the same `body` both in the text part and the html part of the email. The point is that every email should have two alternatives: one in plain text (i.e. without any tags) and one in html. Now people reading your email on a client that doesn't render HTML still will have difficulty reading the email because the text/plain part still contains HTML tags

Comment: yes that is true, do you suggest any edit in code, because I don't know how to do that

Comment: does `msg.attach_alternative(body, 'text/plain')` will solve it

Comment: No, it's not that simple, there is already a 'text/plain' part, which you create when you do `EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, ...)`. The problem is that you are sending `body` (which is HTML) as the text/plain part. Your answer is correct. But you might want to think about a way of generating the text/plain part. Or just send a simple link to the page online in your text/plain part.

Comment: Note that many people doubt the utility of having a `text/plain` part, since almost all email clients handle the HTML part. But if I read an email on my smartwatch, it only shows the text/plain part.

Comment: I read the documentation and i got the idea how to do it. Thank you @dirkgroten